# Independent filtering & sorting on questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

I would like to be able to apply filters and sorting independently when viewing questions.

For example, if I go to the MVC3 tag and click the [unanswered tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) (a *filter*), it is sorted by most votes, and I can't change the sort to, say, most recently active.

Alternatively, if I click the [active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3?sort=active&pagesize=50) (a *sort*), it shows all questions (unfiltered), sorted by most recently active.

It would be nice -- maybe for users that exceed a certain reputation, to prevent confusion for newer members -- to have the option to have custom, or at least independent, sorting & filtering.

Ideally, the tabs would be *either* a sort *or* a filter -- not a confusing combination of the two.

Again, I'm sure this decision was made for simplicity of the UX, but it's at the expense of a functional UX. And again, if simplicity was the driving force behind the decision, then open the option for those with more reputation.

If, however, this is about performance/caching, then personally I say -1 for performance over function.

Comment: I agree with the overall idea but not with the need for  a reputation requirement - lurkers could actually be power users and why deny the function to guests when they can already write answers and questions etc.

Comment: My suggestion was actually comprimising with what I thought may have been the original intent. But if I had my way, I would agree that this should be the default behavior.

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question. +1